# Image not found with Rails 6 and webpack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, webpacker

```
Rails 6
Webpacker
```

In my app/javascript/packs/application.js, I have the following:

```
const images = require.context('../images', true)
const imagePath = (name) => images(name, true)
```

and in the app/javascript/images folder, I added an image:

```
my_company_logo.svg
```

I am trying to use this image in a view, as follows:

```
= image_pack_tag 'my_company_logo'
```

In webpacker.yml, I have the following:

```
webpack_compile_output: true
compile: true
```

And I re-run my application

However, when I try to run the application, I get the following error message:

```
Webpacker can't find my_company_logo in /myapp/public/packs/manifest.json. Possible causes:
1. You want to set webpacker.yml value of compile to true for your environment
   unless you are using the `webpack -w` or the webpack-dev-server.
2. webpack has not yet re-run to reflect updates.
3. You have misconfigured Webpacker's config/webpacker.yml file.
4. Your webpack configuration is not creating a manifest.
Your manifest contains:
{
  "application.js": "/packs/js/application-0c5dbf084c0853e7bb12.js",
  "application.js.map": "/packs/js/application-0c5dbf084c0853e7bb12.js.map",
  "entrypoints": {
    "application": {
      "js": [
        "/packs/js/application-0c5dbf084c0853e7bb12.js"
      ],
      "js.map": [
        "/packs/js/application-0c5dbf084c0853e7bb12.js.map"
      ]
    },
    "books": {
      "js": [
        "/packs/js/books-afabcf18be852ccbec8b.js"
      ],
      "js.map": [
        "/packs/js/books-afabcf18be852ccbec8b.js.map"
      ]
    }
  },
  "media/images/my_company_logo.svg": "/packs/media/images/my_company_logo-7f2088787060688b66225e0671589919.svg",
  "media/webfonts/fa-solid-900.eot": "/packs/media/webfonts/fa-solid-900-89e02bae.eot",
  "media/webfonts/fa-solid-900.svg": "/packs/media/webfonts/fa-solid-900-0724bb8b.svg",
  "media/webfonts/fa-solid-900.ttf": "/packs/media/webfonts/fa-solid-900-75f38a15.ttf",
  "media/webfonts/fa-solid-900.woff": "/packs/media/webfonts/fa-solid-900-cdfec5cf.woff",
  "media/webfonts/fa-solid-900.woff2": "/packs/media/webfonts/fa-solid-900-55eb2a60.woff2",
  "books.js": "/packs/js/books-afabcf18be852ccbec8b.js",
  "books.js.map": "/packs/js/books-afabcf18be852ccbec8b.js.map"
}
```

Any ideas?

## solution:

With webpacker, you need to include the media prefix:

```
= image_pack_tag 'media/images/my_company_logo'
```

Comment: I think it's because of .svg file.

Comment: svg files are supported

Comment: In my project, I have got issues with .svg file because svg file contains xml code.

Comment: This is orthogonal to the problem I am facing. Despite the file being there, it's not finding it.

Comment: Possibility of given path for file may be wrong. Did you checked that too?

Comment: I edited my question with the solution

Comment: Yeah, image path..

Comment: Did you solve it? My solution is `= image_pack_tag 'media/images/my_company_logo.png/jpeg/svg'`, I have included the file type suffix.

Comment: See my edited question for the solution. You don't need to include a suffix